# Why is mapPadding Prop not giving any padding on iOS devices when padding is specified?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I'm having an issue in which upon rendering a map using react-native-maps we are not able to display map padding on iOS devices only.

It's interesting because, Android devices do display the map padding properly, but iOS devices won't show any padding at all when that prop is set.

Here is the following code that works on Android devices but **NOT** iOS devices in regards to mapPadding:

```
 <MapView
          ref={(map) => (this.map = map)}
          mapPadding={{ top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 550, left: 0 }}
          paddingAdjustmentBehavior="always"
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 30.2303 - 0.0123,
            longitude: -97.7538,
            latitudeDelta: 0.2,
            longitudeDelta: 0.1,
          }}
          style={styles.mapStyle}
        >
          {crawlCard.map((crawl, index) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: crawl.coords.lat,
                  longitude: crawl.coords.lon,
                }}
                title={crawl.title}
                key={index}
                onSelect={() => {
                  this.map.animateToRegion(
                    {
                      latitude: crawl.coords.lat,
                      longitude: crawl.coords.lon,
                    },
                    200
                  );
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
```

Is there any other function/method we need to implement to get this mapPadding prop to work on iOS devices? All examples my team & I have seen have used the mapPadding just like this for both platforms.

We're using:
React Native 5.x
react-native-maps 0.26.1

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to get `mapPadding` to work the same on both platforms was to use `provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}`, which requires some additional configuration to work on iOS. That makes the map look and work mostly identically on both platforms though.